# On publishing infopath 2010 form loses control properties - dropdown control data binding setting

Tags: infopath

I am try to created a cascade dropdown using infopath 2010 in sharepoint 2010 list. On publishing infopath form i lost data binding setting and it just resets to default "Enter choices manually". It works perfectly only if i dont publish it (preview mode). I even recreated infopath form many times but of no use. It works perfectly on some other site but not on where i want to.
[note: Dropdown are lookup columns]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are getting additional value from the Infopath form, consider using [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) from [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) for your cascading. No fuss, no muss.